# List of tables/figures without their captions

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to have a list of tables and figures with their page numbers.

Using:

```
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

will produce a list like below:

```
List of Tables
Table#  Caption ................. Page#
Table#  Caption ................. Page#
```

But I would like to have:

```
List of Tables
Table# .......................... Page#
Table# .......................... Page#
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Quick hack: `\caption[]{your caption text}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In order to be able to tell you how to remove the captions from the list of tables by changing some parameter in the preamble, you have to tell us your settings, in particular your document class. Please provide a *complete* small document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that contains the main features of your document and that can be compiled.

Comment: @samcarter: Could get tedious ;-)

Comment: @samcarter I tried this before posting the question but in my case that will remove the table/figure from the list. \caption[ ]{your caption test} (with a whitespace) would work though.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer "global replace" is a nice thing to have. But apparently the hack is not even working, so big fail :)

Comment: @samcarter: ????

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Replacing all `\section` with `\section[]` does not have to be tedious, just one time using "replace all" which every decent editor should have. But it does not really matter, without an additional white space or an empty box of some kind, my proposed hack is not working anyway. And your solution is definitely the better way to go :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick hack with redefinition of `\caption`.

If the `\ifnumberonly` boolean test is true, then the usual caption content is displayed in the body but omitted in the `Lof` or `LoT`

Say `\numberonlytrue` to enable the 'easy' display in the `LoT` or `\numberonlyfalse` for the usual content.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgffor}


\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifnumberonly
\numberonlytrue

\makeatletter
\let\caption@@orig\caption

\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \caption@@orig*{#3}%
  }{%
    \ifnumberonly
    \caption@@orig[]{#3}
    \else
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \caption@@orig[#2]{#3}
    }{%
      \caption@@orig{#3}
    }%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listoffigures
\foreach \x in {1,...,20}{%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure \x\ but you won't see this}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table \x\ but you won't see this}
\end{table}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]